# Passing setInterval() to a variable but fires off immediately

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm trying to understand why this code fires off immediately.

```
const test = setInterval(() => {
  console.log("test"), 2;
});
```

Why does it happen? I didn't even do `test();`

Comment: setInterval doesn't return a function, it returns an id number so that you can cancel it later.

Comment: you made a missing of `arrow function` syntax. `const test = () => setInterval(() => console.log("test"), 2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to pass `2` as an argument to `setInterval` - currently it's not available. Also note that the only reason anyone assigns the result of `setInterval` is to call `clearInterval`. If you want to have it run when you want, make `test` a function.

```
const test = () => setInterval(() => console.log("test"), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such syntax errors we can do like this,

```
const test = setInterval(myTest, 2);

function myTest() {
   console.log("test")
}
```

Make sure to stop your `setInterval` function when not in use,

```
function myStopFunction() {
  clearInterval(test);
}
```